# Exporting a Powershell object containing multiple arrays to CSV/Power BI

Tags: powershell, csv, powerbi

It's Friday and my brain's just not working! I have a Powershell object which is the result of DSInternals Test-PasswordQuality cmdlet that I'd like to use as a Power BI dataset; it's a bunch of arrays of user accounts, ex.

```
ClearTextPassword          : {}
LMHash                     : {someuser, another user...}
EmptyPassword              : {someuser, another user}
WeakPassword               : {someuser, another user...}
DefaultComputerPassword    : {etc...}
PasswordNotRequired        : {etc...}
PasswordNeverExpires       : {etc...}
AESKeysMissing             : {etc...}
PreAuthNotRequired         : {}
DESEncryptionOnly          : {}
Kerberoastable             : {}
DelegatableAdmins          : {}
SmartCardUsersWithPassword : {}
DuplicatePasswordGroups    : {}
```

I'd like to export this to one csv where each array is its own column. If I simply do

```
$result | export-csv .\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I do get a column for each array, but then the users in each column are all combined into one cell.

[example of first few columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi6q2.png)

How can I get the same, but with each user in it's own cell?

OR, how can I get this PS object directly into a Power BI dataset with maybe the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt module?

Thanks a million y'all!

Comment: This is not too complicated considering the properties seem to contain array of strings, if however, they had nested objects it might be more complicated. Can you confirm these are array of strings?

Comment: Yes they're arrays of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object in this answer is a minimal representation of yours and is meant for the sake of demonstrating the method you can use.

First, you need to calculate the maximum count of elements of all properties, for this, we can access the [`PSObject.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and *for each value*, get it's count. Then, we can use a [`for` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2) to reconstruct it.

```
$object = [pscustomobject]@{
    ClearTextPassword       = @()
    EmptyPassword           = @('someuser', 'another user', 'yet another')
    WeakPassword            = @('someuser', 'another user')
    DefaultComputerPassword = @('etc')
    PasswordNotRequired     = @(1,2,3,4,5)
}

$max = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Max($object.PSObject.Properties.ForEach({ $_.Value.Count }))

$result = for($i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++) {
    $outObject = [ordered]@{}
    foreach($prop in $object.PSObject.Properties) {
        $outObject[$prop.Name] = $prop.Value[$i]
    }
    [pscustomobject]$outObject
}

$result | Format-Table
```

Example above would result in the following `object[]`, which, should be perfectly fine for export to CSV.

```
ClearTextPassword EmptyPassword WeakPassword DefaultComputerPassword PasswordNotRequired
----------------- ------------- ------------ ----------------------- -------------------
                  someuser      someuser     etc                                       1
                  another user  another user                                           2
                  yet another                                                          3
                                                                                       4
                                                                                       5
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Much obliged friend

Comment: How much does it complicate things if they are sets instead of arrays? Turns out the data I was working with (which were arrays) were retrieved from the original object being piped to "Export-Clixml". When working with the original object, they are sets, i.e.

`ClearTextPassword          Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] ClearTextPassword {get;set;}`

Comment: @lohash best way to parse it would be to ask a new question providing a representation of the XML in the question so it's easier for us to parse it into a flat object